# ERROR SVMCLASSIFY MATLAB out of memery

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I have this script in Matlab

struct = svmTraining(feature_train,class_final_train);

svmclassify(struct,feature_test);

but, after 5 seconds the following message appears

??? Error using ==> svmclassify at 117
An error was encountered during classification.
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Help me, Thanks

Comment: Have you at least try something to solve it? Like googling? Or anything else?

Comment: Of course, but I did not solve the problem.... I have to classify each pixel of a image from 18 images. My training set has about 900.000 rows, each row has 5 double. The svmclassify function after 5 seconds throws this exception...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this same problem for myself by calling the svmclassify() function on successive subsets of the test data. For some reason it needs an enormous amount of memory if you give it a large array of test data.

So here is something that worked for me

```
numExemplars = size(testData,1);
chunkSize = 1000;
j=1:chunkSize:numExemplars;
classifications = zeros(numExemplars,1);  %initialize
for i=1:length(j)-1;
    index1 = j(i);
    index2 = j(i+1)-1;
    fprintf('classifying exemplars %d to %d\n', index1, index2 );
    chunk = testData(index1:index2,:);
    classifications(index1:index2) = svmclassify(SVM_struct,chunk);
end
% last bit of data
chunk = testData(j(end):numExemplars,:);
classifications(j(end):numExemplars) = svmclassify(SVM_struct,chunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you do not have enough memory available on your machine to carry out the classification.

Firstly, try repeating the commands with a freshly started MATLAB, without creating any more variables than necessary, and with no other applications running.

If that doesn't work, then essentially you will need to either work with a smaller dataset, or get more memory for your machine.

Comment: I have done this, but the problem has remained.Is there a solution? My training set has 200000 rows about. Thanks.

Comment: If you are only slightly running out of memory, then there may be some tricks you can find to make your problem squeeze into memory, but probably the real solution is to either use a smaller dataset, or to get more memory for your machine.